# How to create TightVNC server "Attach Listening Viewer" shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, tightvnc

When You need to connect remotely to someone's desktop, and his computer is behind a NAT, You can use reverse VNC connection. You do it by using TightVNC Server's "Attach Listening Viewer" option. It requires manual selection of that option, and manual typing of IP adress.

Is there a way to avoid this manual activity by creating shortcut ( command line ) with fixed IP address and port ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. To do it use simple command like this:

`"c:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe" -controlservice -connect ip-address:port-number`

For ip-addres Use IP address of the computer that runs actual VNC client ( which is about to control the desktop )

Answer (score 2):

Shortcut for launching the server as user app (for those not running it as service) and connecting.

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe" -run && timeout 1 && "%PROGRAMFILES%\TightVNC\tvnserver.exe" -controlapp -connect IPADDRESS`

Answer (score 0):

I want VNC to a local computer at IP 10.0.1.11 using a desktop shortcut so I can just double click it. The above did not work. Using help (in CMD) I find the instructions to be:

tvnviewer hostname::port [OPTIONS]

Example that works using TightVNC:

1. Create a shortcut on your desktop from the 'Program Files' folder (or x86)
2. Right-click the shortcut, choose Properties.
3. In the 1st editable line labeled 'Target:' add this after the string that is already there: 10.0.1.11::5900 so your string now looks like this:

"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" 10.0.1.11::5900

Obviously change 10.0.1.11 to whatever IP address you want to control.
Also go to the General tab and change the name of the shortcut to something appropriate like "Connect to Laptop" or "My Mac", etc.

Tested on my Windows 8.1 Pro PC with TightVNC 2.7.10.0.